# RAID failure notifications

Tags: macos, disk-utility, automation, raid

I recently bought a Mac Mini to use as a NAS, among other things. I'm thinking about setting up a couple external drives as a RAID 1 (mirrored) set to help safeguard my data in case one of them goes bad.

I doubt I will be using a monitor with the computer very often and I'm afraid that a dialog box or notification will sit there for months, unnoticed, while I continue to use the drive over the network.

I would prefer to be emailed or notified on my iPhone.

When a disk goes bad, how does the system notify you?

Comment: I wrote a simple AppleRAID monitor script quite a while back; it's on ServerFault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/153956/mac-os-x-server-10-6-apples-software-mirrored-raid-worth-it/154344#154344). I haven't tested (or used) it in a long time, but as far as I know it should still work.

Comment: If you go software RAID you almost surely want https://www.softraid.com/versions/

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to find on Apple's discussion site (examples [1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1316662), [2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252456294), [3](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/276843?db=5), [4](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/912950)), it appears that macOS Server (discontinued) has notification options for RAID failures but the normal consumer version of macOS does not. Instead, you can check the status yourself in Disk Utility or rely on a 3rd party tool.

For that reason, I've decided to return the Mac Mini (it hasn't even arrived yet) and get a Synology NAS instead.